# Oracle - Update when case taking long time

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-optimization

I have a table with the following columns:

```
val      range_from      range_to    final_val
-2.12    -2                  2               -2
-0.12    -2                  2               -0.12
-0.12    -2                  2               -0.12
1.51     -2                  2               1.51
-1.29    -2                  2               -1.29
2.23     -2                  2               2
```

final_val is something which I need to calculate using the following condition:

```
update table1
SET final_val= case
when val > range_to then range_to
when val < range_from then range_from
else VAL
END;
```

My table definition:

```
Name       Null Type   
---------- ---- ------ 
VAL             NUMBER 
RANGE_FROM      NUMBER 
RANGE_TO        NUMBER 
FINAL_VAL       NUMBER
```

I do not have any indexes on the table

The above query is taking long to execute. The table size is of 30GB. It is taking more than 16 hours to execute it.

Is there a better way to get this done?

Comment: You'll need to provide much more information. Starting with a full definition of the table including all indexes. Additional: a quick calc estimates you have ~500 million rows,, in 16 hours that's >8000 updates per second: is that slow?

Comment: The amount of space a table takes up on disk is not really relevant to performance. More useful in this case (and most others) would be number of rows. Whether there are indexes on it. What else is happening in the database when you run the update

Comment: There are no indexes in this table, should I add any for this operation?

Comment: Indexes won't help speed things up, because you're updating every row in the table. In fact indexes would slow things down, if you had to maintain an index over `final_val`.

Comment: So what do you do with a 500m row table which has no indexes?

Comment: I will add indexes later once update is complete.

Comment: Rather than updating rows could you add a computed column?

Comment: Your using a single transaction for this, which means writing all the changes to the redo log, and then at the end to the data file. How about doing the updates in batches each in its own transaction? (You can filter on `val not between range_from and range_to`.)

Comment: Is it on purpose that the columns are nullable? Especially for the ranges to mean "no limit"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are updating every record in the table and Oracle does obey, i.e. even when not changing the `final_val` value, the record will get updated. So the first measure would be to only update records that must be updated, e.g.:

```
UPDATE table1
SET final_val = case when val > range_to then range_to 
                     when val < range_from then range_from 
                     else val 
                end
WHERE final_val <> case when val > range_to then range_to 
                        when val < range_from then range_from 
                        else val
                   end;
```

(You may have to adjust this in case the columns can be null. E.g.: `WHERE DECODE(final_val, case when ... end, 'equal', 'different') = 'different'`.)

Then you may have a machine that can perform parallel operations. So a hint may work:

```
UPDATE /*+parallel(table1,8)*/ table1
SET final_val = case when val > range_to then range_to 
                     when val < range_from then range_from 
                     else val 
                end
WHERE final_val <> case when val > range_to then range_to 
                        when val < range_from then range_from 
                        else val
                   end;
```

It seems likely, however, that you want `final_val` always to be the value computed from `val`, `range_from` and `range_to`. In that case, why update at all? Write a view or use a virtual column instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
update table1 SET final_val = val where val between range_from and range_to;
update table1 SET final_val = range_from where val < range_from;
update table1 SET final_val = range_to where val > range_to;
```

Comment: Won't it take longer for 3 queries than 1 query?

Comment: It's certainly the way to bet, given there are no indexes

Answer (score 0):

1. First you should look at the indexes and constraints. If there are any, it could be better to temporary drop them and get them back after the update.
2. Sometimes it is faster to create a temporary table based on select than to update a table. You can try it.